# Python selenium gets 111 socket error

Tags: python, selenium

I'm just running the example code of selenium from here:

http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/index.html

The code is :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Get local session of firefox
browser.get("http://www.yahoo.com") # Load page
try:
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'http://seleniumhq.org')]")
except NoSuchElementException:
    assert 0, "can't find seleniumhq"
browser.close()
```

But It doesn't work for me, here's what it response:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 72, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 114, in start_session
    'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 165, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 136, in check_response
    raise exception_class(value)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message:
...
<div id="content">
<p>The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: <a href="http://127.0.0.1:60106/hub/session">http://127.0.0.1:60106/hub/session</a></p>

<blockquote id="error">
<p><b>Connection to 127.0.0.1 failed.</b></p>
</blockquote>

<p id="sysmsg">The system returned: <i>(111) Connection refused</i></p>

<p>The remote host or network may be down. Please try the request again.</p>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you aren't running the full example.  The link you posted contains the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Get local session of firefox
browser.get("http://www.yahoo.com") # Load page
assert "Yahoo!" in browser.title
elem = browser.find_element_by_name("p") # Find the query box
elem.send_keys("seleniumhq" + Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(0.2) # Let the page load, will be added to the API
try:
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'http://seleniumhq.org')]")
except NoSuchElementException:
    assert 0, "can't find seleniumhq"
browser.close()
```

this works fine.
The edited version of the code in your question is missing some parts, and therefore fails.  Specifically, you are missing these 2 lines:

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_name("p") # Find the query box
elem.send_keys("seleniumhq" + Keys.RETURN)
```

That initiates a Yahoo search for "seleniumhq".  The results of that search is the content where you want to locate the element.

if you don't do the search, it will fail on:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'http://seleniumhq.org')]")
```

Comment: I've tried the full example, but it doesn't either. I think the problem is I didn't refer to `127.0.0.1`, but the error shows that it is trying to reach `127.0.0.1:xxxxx`

Comment: @MrRoy:  interesting.  any any chance your network connection uses a proxy server ('HTTP_PROXY' environment var), or you have a firewall running on the local machine?

Comment: Yes, I'm in an internal network and of course we have a firewall, but the firewall didn't block any website as I know ...

Comment: I meant a firewall locally on the machine you are running from... not just behind a corporate firewall.  hmm.. 127.0.0.1 is your local loopback address.  I would start by verifying that.

Answer (score 0):

When Selenium launches Firefox with

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

the first address it visits is a localhost - 127.0.0.1:xxxxx

If you are using a proxy server, the localhost cannot be visited with the proxy set.
So, first you need to turn off your proxies using:

```
unset http_proxy
unset ftp_proxy
unset socks_proxy
unset https_proxy
```

Once you have turned your proxies off, your Firefox should start without any error. But now you need to set your proxies on Firefox. The technique described [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#using-a-proxy) works.